# jquery toggle show div

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

I have a chat feature on my site, and users click a button to open it

```
$(function() { 
$('#chat').hide(); // hides the chat on load

$("#chat_btn").click(function(){ 
    $('#chat').show();
    $('#chat').load("chat.php");
    }); 
});
```

This all works fine, but I want to be able to click the same button to close the chat too.

I know there's some kind of toggle function instead of hide and show, but I want the other command (load the chat.php) to run only on the open.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you load your chat.php more then once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the other [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function: it takes two (or more) event handlers: the first is called the first time, the second the second time, the first the third time, etc.

```
$("#chat_btn").toggle(function(){ // run the first time
    $('#chat').show();
    $('#chat').load("chat.php");
}, function() { // run the second time
    $('#chat').hide();
});
```

NB that you could make this (a tiny bit) more efficient by chaining the `show` and `load` calls:

```
    $('#chat').show().load("chat.php");
```

Comment: Interesting point. I dont see this in the jQuery docs (or maybe I am not reading it correctly). Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Jeff The `toggle` effect (that's linked) or the chaining?

Answer (score 1):

The `:visible` pseudo-selector should be able to identify whether or not the chat window is open (assuming you arent using any other CSS trickery that you have not included)

```
var $chat = $('#chat');

if($chat.is(':visible'))
    $chat.hide()
else
{
    $chat.show();
    $chat.load(...);
}
```

Comment: why waste the extra time on an extra selector (especially one as slow as :visible)? `toggle()` does the same job, but better.

Comment: On open, the script should load a php page. On close that shouldn't happen. Until I read lonesomeday's response, I was unaware of anyway to distinguish between opening and closing via `.toggle`. In fact, I just reread the docs and I still dont see that mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chat_btn').click(function() {
  $('#chat').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

jquery has the .toggle() method.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @lonesomeday has a complete answer, I +1ed his post.